# Why does booting Fedora 17 (and 18) into virtualbox from a live cd fail?

Tags: windows-7, linux, virtualbox, fedora, iso-image

Background: I was recently trying to install Fedora 18 into Virtualbox. The version of virtualbox is listed as: 4.2.14.0. My host system is 64 bit Windows 7 home premium. My processor (Intel Pentium B940) will only host 32 bit vm Operating Systems. The Fedora release I downloaded and tried to install is: Fedora-17-x86_64-Live-Desktop.iso

Virtual box can see (and read?) the live CD .iso. I get this far:

[image: LoadScreen]

but then it hangs never loading the OS:

[image: HangScreen]

I'm pretty sure that I have the storage/load settings correct:
[image: StorageSettings]

Here are the Network settings:

[image: Network]

Here are the System settings:

[image]

I was able to successfully load Fedora 15 from a DVD .iso (Fedora-15-i386-DVD.iso).
I have Win7 (en_windows_7_professional_with_sp1_x86_dvd_u_677056.iso) loaded in a virtual machine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're processor *does* support 64-bit OS's natively ([CPU specs](http://ark.intel.com/products/55626/Intel-Pentium-Processor-B940-2M-Cache-2_00-GHz)).

My understanding is that you're saying you are running Windows 7 Home Premium 32-bit.

The ISO name "Fedora-17-x86_64-Live-Desktop.iso" points out that the Fedora version is 64-bit (x86_64).

You can't run a 64-bit VirtualBox guest on a 32-bit host OS unless you processor supports both 64-bit instructions (which yours does) and hardware virtualization (which yours does not).  [Related info from VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#intro-64bitguests)

So, either run a 32-bit (i386) of Fedora in the VM, or replace your host OS (Windows) version with a 64-bit version, or upgrade your CPU to one that supports both 64-bit and hardware virtualization.

Comment: Since x86 is almost synonymous with 32 bit architecture, i didn't register that it was 64 bit. I feel like a dope. Now it makes sense that the i386 Fedora 15 release loaded easily. I edited my question to reflect that the host system is 64-bit, but the processor only supports 32-bit vms.

Comment: No reason to feel like a dope, I can totally see how you'd think that.