# Why does booting Fedora 28 & 29 live .iso failing on VirtualBox

Tags: linux, windows-10, virtualbox, fedora, iso-image

I'm having nearly the same problem as stated in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/613262/why-does-booting-fedora-17-and-18-into-virtualbox-from-a-live-cd-fail).  Same symptom at the same stage in the process.  I, however, believe I am loading a 32bit .iso:

Fedora-Workstation-Live-i386-28-1.1 (same response with corresponding Fedora 29 image)

Host Machine:
CPU: Core™ i7-8550U
OS: Windows 10 Home

Virtual Config
2GB Memory
40GB Storage

Comment: Please provide more information about the host OS and the machine’s hardware

Comment: Try enabling/disabling 3D/2D acceleration. One setting should theoretically boot correctly a Fedora live session. But a corrupt ISO is also possible.

Comment: Hard Drive is 1TB Solid State, 32 GB ram, Windows is 64 bit. What else may be of use here?

Comment: I am able to enable 3D acceleration with no change in behavior.  2D Acceleration "Invalid settings detected".  No change in behavior with 3D, still a black screen with the exception of a blinking cursor in the top left "_"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the BIOS of the host machine needed to be configured to support Virtualization.  VT-x/AMD-V.  Once enabled, things got rolling.

[Tutorial from HowToGeek](https://www.howtogeek.com/213795/how-to-enable-intel-vt-x-in-your-computers-bios-or-uefi-firmware/)